# How to call method sliding menu from another class?

Tags: android, class, methods, menu, sliding

i create menu using jeremyfeinstein, like below :
    import android.app.Activity;

```
import com.e_campus.tesapp.R;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

public class Menu extends Activity {

    public void setupMenu(){
        SlidingMenu slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slide_menu);
    }
}
```

after that, this sliding menu method "setupMenu" i call in another class like :

```
public class C_News extends Activity{


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
       TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titlePage);
       title.setText("News & Information");
       Menu sliding = new Menu();
       sliding.setupMenu();

   }

}
```

but, when i run display error

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: I think it would be better to call your setupMenu method from the onCreate in the class Menu. Then you will never have a not initialized Menu class. Probably this will also solve your nullpointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse in other Activits

```
public class Menu {

public static void setupMenu(Context context){
    SlidingMenu slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(context);
    slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
    slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    slidingMenu.attachToActivity(context, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slide_menu);
}
```

}

Comment: sory change slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT); to slidingMenu.attachToActivity(context, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);

Comment: My previous display menu by slidingmenu.toggle (), but once it is made like method above, display error "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.toggle()' on a null object reference"